# How to solve "Couldn't find an AF_INET address for " problem

Tags: ros, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am running four computers with only one the ROS master, and I am sure I set the correct ROS_MASTER_URI (=http://192.168.10.101:11311) to the other three computers. Then the problems like this:
I run a node in the master computer, and also I publish some message to that node. In this master computer, I can use "rostopic echo" to see the published messages, but in  another computer, if I run "rostopic list", I see all the topics, but if I run "rostopic echo /xxxx" then I cannot see anything. Most importantly, I see the master computer threw out a message saying `Couldn't find an AF_INET address for [msl]`. It is probably some network problem, so please help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/163556/how-to-solve-%22couldn%27t-find-an-af_inet-address-for-%22-problem/) by [skyhawk](https://answers.ros.org/users/17746/skyhawk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 201 on 2014-05-10

Post score: 13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

skyhawk is right, set the ROS_IP for each computer. So for each computer, find the IP address in a terminal with

```
hostname -I
```

It will be the first set of numbers, like 10.0.0.25. To set it,

```
export ROS_IP=10.0.0.25
```

Make sure you're exporting the right address on each one, it'll be different for each computer.

---

Originally posted by [mattc12345](https://answers.ros.org/users/19817/mattc12345/) with karma: 328 on 2014-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 30

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fabbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/20381/fabbro/) on 2019-10-08**:
This worked for me! Thanks

**Comment by [blubbi321](https://answers.ros.org/users/23248/blubbi321/) on 2020-05-22**:
(as mentioned in posts below): In case this does not solve your problem edit `/etc/hosts` to contain the name for the rosnode. For example in there add
`192.168.3.5   my_hostname`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should set the ROS_IP for each computer that is in the network running the ROS.

---

Originally posted by [skyhawk](https://answers.ros.org/users/17746/skyhawk/) with karma: 201 on 2014-05-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Or just set on every computer in you network (so you don't have to thing about addresses):

```
export ROS_IP=`hostname -I`
```

Or even, sometimes better, solution is to add this line in your .bashrc file.

---

Originally posted by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) with karma: 877 on 2014-09-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-09-04**:
Be warned - this only works if your computer only has one IP address. If you have two addresses, perhaps ethernet and WiFi, hostname -I will show multiple addresses and your ROS_IP will probably be invalid.

**Comment by [cellard0or](https://answers.ros.org/users/27123/cellard0or/) on 2016-08-03**:
@ahendrix In the case of multiple addresses, what address do have to set ROS_IP to? I set it to the one which used for communication between host and the ROS PC but it did not work.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-08-03**:
@cellard0or : that approach should work, but you've given very little information. Please ask a new question with details about your setup and the errors you're encountering.

**Comment by [blubbi321](https://answers.ros.org/users/23248/blubbi321/) on 2017-11-01**:
as current ubuntu revisions seem to report more than just the ip when calling hostname -I I used

```
machine_ip=(`hostname -I`)
export ROS_IP=${machine_ip[0]}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The only solution that worked for me was to list the ip address of each computer along with
its hostname to the /etc/hosts file.

---

Originally posted by [dim_sgou](https://answers.ros.org/users/20637/dim_sgou/) with karma: 96 on 2015-03-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pulver](https://answers.ros.org/users/22461/pulver/) on 2015-06-08**:
Thank you! In my case, having two ip address on the robot and two on the workstation, this was the only one working solution!

**Comment by [blubbi321](https://answers.ros.org/users/23248/blubbi321/) on 2020-05-22**:
I also already had the suggested #1 solution implemented and this helped to get rid of the error

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If this is  coming from a gazebo plugin -- it may be because gazebo is beignn run standalone  rather than launched from ros as required.

---

Originally posted by [charles.fox](https://answers.ros.org/users/22231/charles.fox/) with karma: 120 on 2015-11-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would say the best answer...
worked 100% for my robot and local computers.
have a look...
[http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~cteo/umd-erratic-ros-data/README-rvis-remote](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/%7Ecteo/umd-erratic-ros-data/README-rvis-remote)

---

Originally posted by [Farid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25360/farid/) with karma: 165 on 2016-01-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found a way, change your /etc/hosts
Such as:

```
vim /etc/hosts
```

then add your ip:

```
192.168.3.5   my_hostname
```

---

Originally posted by [TifferPelode](https://answers.ros.org/users/27959/tifferpelode/) with karma: 96 on 2016-09-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kotoko](https://answers.ros.org/users/27417/kotoko/) on 2018-08-06**:
This was the only thing that worked for me after adding ROS_IP